# Wrong item layout direction in StaggeredGridLayoutManager unsing RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, staggeredgridlayout

I am facing issues while placing items in staggered view vertically with span count 2. if the item count is 3 and first item height is greater, third item is aligning to right(4th place)leaving 3rd item empty.

Comment: Mind showing some code?

Comment: layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        `layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS); gridView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

Comment: Edit your question and move your code there. I would also add a screenshot.